# Travis CI C++ Build succeed but travis exited with 1 and doesn't passes the test

Tags: c++, cmake, travis-ci

I am trying to integrate my project with Travis CI, and when i build it everything seems to be ok, but the built is still failing and I get the message
Done. Your build exited with 1. but the CMake build give me message The command "cmake --build . -- -j2" exited with 0.

Here is my outupt of the build in travis-ci :
https://travis-ci.org/stelro/Fission-Engine
Here is the CMakeList.txt of the project:
https://github.com/stelro/Fission-Engine/blob/EntityComponentSystem/CMakeLists.txt
And here is the travis.yml:
https://github.com/stelro/Fission-Engine/blob/EntityComponentSystem/.travis.yml

Can someone help me and explaine me why I cannot pass the travis-ci build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to install gcc-6 and set up links manually. Operations such as

```
ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-6 /usr/local/bin/gcc
```

require sudo which is disabled in your .travis.yml file. The better approach would be to specify gcc-6 as part of your build matrix:

```
matrix:
  include:
  # g++ builds
  - os: linux
    addons:
      apt:
        sources:
        - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test
        packages:
        - g++-6
    env:
    - COMPILER="g++-6"
```

Comment: Thank you. this worked, but I had to add for some reasone this too : install: export CXX="g++-6"